# Passing multiple variables from dropdowns using Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Python. I would like display results based on multiple selections from dropdowns.

The following code is working and returning the correct results for one dropdown.  I would like to add at least one more dropdown, hopefully multiple, but I cannot fathom how to achieve passing and returning the multiple vars.

Form code

```
        <p> <form method="get" action="">

            <select name="search3">
                {% for cs in course_list %}
                    <option value="{{ cs.pk }}">{{ cs.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <br/><br/>

            <input type=submit value="Find staff" />
            </form>
    </p>



    {% if employee_list %}
        {{ employee_list.count }} employees matching : <strong>{{ course }}</strong><br/><br/>
        {% for e in employee_list %}
        {% if not e.img1 %}
            <img src="/media/images/null_image.png" width="35"  title="{{ e.first_name}} {{e.surname }}" />
        {% else %}
            <img src="{{ e.img1.url }}" width="50" title="{{ e.first_name}} {{e.surname }}"/>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="/employee/{{ e.slug }}" target="_blank" rel="popup" title="Details...<br />
            {% for det in employee_list.employeedynamic_set.all %}
            {{ det.mobile }}<br />
            {{ det.depot }}<br />
            {% endfor %}
        ">&nbsp;{{ e.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ e.surname }}</a><br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No employees matched: <strong>{{ course }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}
```

views.py code

```
#   function to list training courses and participating uindividuals.
def CourseView(request):

    course_list     = Course.objects.all().order_by('name')
    if 'search3' in request.GET:
        search3     = request.GET['search3']
        course      = Course.objects.get(pk=search3)
    else:
        search3 = None
        course = None

    return render_to_response("course_display.html", {'course':course,  'course_list': course_list, 'search3': search3 })
```

Is it possible to add an another dropdown option or even multiple dropdown options and get a result.  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**UPDATE.**

In order to pass one or multiple variables back to my function the code is simply the following

```
def CompetencyCheck(request):
    course_list = Course.objects.all()
    if 'search3' in request.GET:
        search3 = request.GET.getlist('search3')
        course = Course.objects.filter(id__in=search3).distinct().order_by()
```

*.get()* allows only the last variable passed from the web page form to be read/passed back to the function.
On the other hand, the *.getlist()* allows one or multiple vars to be passed back.  Great, part the of problem solved.

The list of names being returned is unique in that if var1 returns 4 names and var2 returns 8 names and both vars have one common name, a list of 11 names in returned.

I want only the common names to both vars returned, *i.e.* 1 name to be returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your question is. Exactly where are you having problems?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I would like to be able to pass two vars (from two dropdowns) from form and display results

Answer (score 1):

`request.GET` in your view is a [dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict); by doing `request.GET['search3']` you're just accessing the value of its `search3` key.  So in your template, you should be able to just add other `<select>` elements with their own names and retrieve their submitted values from `request.GET` in the same way.

Comment: Hi GChorn, I've been reading about QueryDict. Pradeep suggested a possible solution. Upon investigation I noticed that you can assign multiple selections to a var in HTML.

Comment: @TommyGibbons, are you referring to the `<select>` element with the `multiple` attribute?  You can create a single drop-down field from which multiple values can be selected by using `<select multiple>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can query using course_list only.
for example:

```
course_list     = Course.objects.all().order_by('name')
var1 = request.POST.get('var1')
if var1:
    course_list = course_list.objects.filter(some = var1)
var2 = request.POST.get('var2')
if var2:
    course_list = course_list.objects.filter(some = var2)
```

Comment: I've followed you thoughts to find the following <select name="search3" multiple> Using CTRL and one dropdown box you can select multiple vars, http://127.0.0.1:8000/skill_select/?search3=46&search3=40 . But only the last var search3=40 is being displayed.

Comment: Means you are not getting multiple variables. gothrough this link http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget and check.